# make: specify package dependency location

Tags: makefile, static-libraries, configure, autotools

tldr: how can I tell `make` to use a `library.a` instead of searching for the library in `/usr/local/Cellar/`

I have 2 c libraries (1 and 2). I was able to build library 1 for the required architectures and I want to do the same for library 2. Library 2 depends on library 1. If I was to build library 2 for my personal computer it would probably be sufficient to simply install library 1 with brew and then run my build script for library 2. However, as I have to build for other architectures as well, it won't work like that.

I have successfully created the `library 1.a` file with all the needed architectures but I'm unable to find any information on how to make `make` aware that it should relate to this file.

```
for ARCH in ${ARCHS}
do
    if [ "${ARCH}" == "i386" ] || [ "${ARCH}" == "x86_64" ]; then
        PLATFORM="iPhoneSimulator"
        EXTRA_CFLAGS="-arch ${ARCH}"
        EXTRA_CONFIG="--host=x86_64-apple-darwin"
    else
        PLATFORM="iPhoneOS"
        EXTRA_CFLAGS="-arch ${ARCH}"
        EXTRA_CONFIG="--host=arm-apple-darwin"
    fi

    mkdir -p "${INTERDIR}/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk"

    ./configure --enable-float-approx --disable-shared --enable-static --with-pic --disable-extra-programs --disable-doc ${EXTRA_CONFIG} \
    --prefix="${INTERDIR}/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk" \
    LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS ${OPT_LDFLAGS} -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=${MINIOSVERSION} -L${OUTPUTDIR}/lib" \
    CFLAGS="$CFLAGS ${EXTRA_CFLAGS} ${OPT_CFLAGS} -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=${MINIOSVERSION} -I${OUTPUTDIR}/include -isysroot ${DEVELOPER}/Platforms/${PLATFORM}.platform/Developer/SDKs/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}.sdk" \

    make -j4
    make install
    make clean
done
```

I am not very experienced in c - I don't think it's a hard task to achieve but I simply do not know what to google for. If you could let me know what flag/config or command is needed to lead `make` to the `library 1.a` that would be really helpful.

I did find the `-L` flag however specifying the folder doesn't help, it still says

```
configure: error: Package requirements (opus >= 1.1) were not met:

No package 'opus' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables DEPS_CFLAGS
and DEPS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

What I've tried was to add `export DEPS_LIBS=$HOME/Downloads/libopusenc/libopus.a` but it's still the same. Does it also require something in DEPS_CFLAGS? If yes, what could I type there to make it "not empty" if that's what it needs?

do I need to specify the library's name and the name it's searching for directly somehow?

Comment: have you examined the `configure --help`  options?

Comment: @Rorschach Thank you for your response. I did try a few more things now based on this like `--libdir=$REPOROOT` but I'm not sure if I'm using them correctly. Furthermore I have found that the `configure.ac` says `PKG_CHECK_MODULES([DEPS], [opus >= 1.1])`. I think that's the step where it fails, not because of make but because of `./configure`. If I try to comment that out, it will get added back in automatically on next `./configure` call. This is the library in question: https://github.com/xiph/libopusenc

Comment: the configure script is used to generate the makefile with variables specific to your environment, and is unique to different projects - so it's hard to guess exactly what variables need to be changed (perhaps a real autotools eficionado) - to link the static library I don't think you would need to adjust the CFLAGS, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Simply doing `export DEPS_CFLAGS=' '` was enough for the script to skip that step. I did now run into other issues but I will open a new question if I can't figure it out from here